# A Launch Crash about fresco

Tags: android, fresco

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: unlock of unowned monitor on object of type
 'com.facebook.common.references.SharedReference' on thread 
'Thread[127,tid=3297,Runnable,Thread*=0xb9625800,peer=0x13d473f0,"FrescoDecodeExecutor-4"]'
```

Have never encountered this problem, hoping to get answers, thank you！

Comment: r u execute your code in thread?

Comment: @RanjithKumar yes, thread id printed in the crash message

Comment: You'll need to add some code so we know where the error is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your Fresco loader code inside **runOnUiThread**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         //your code
                    }
                });
```